# AMDGPU-PRO 16.60 hangs KDE before login on Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, kde, amdgpu

I tried installing amdgpu-pro downloading it from the official site and after rebooting i'm not able to access KDE anymore. I can access tty, but if i press Alt+Ctrl+F7 i can just get a blinking '_' in the top-left corner of the screen.

Release notes report that this may happen on some platforms, but i'd like to resolve this issue.

I removed the driver running 'amdgpu-pro-uninstall' on the tty. However, stock Mesa has not the best OpenCL support and I need it. Is there a way i can fix this? If not, could you suggest me some alternative drivers that may work for my hardware to run most OpenCL programs? Here is everything you should know about my PC, if you need more logs just ask:

clinfo output: https://gist.github.com/aegroto/d4a9e8d4c6aca7a5d24efb1c5543ef3f

GPU info (RX460) :

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 67ef (rev cf) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 22dd
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 30
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at cfe00000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=2M]
    I/O ports at b000 [size=256]
    Memory at fbc80000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

Linux kernel version: 4.11.0-14-lowlatency

Comment: EDIT: Tried installing AMDGPU-PRO 17.30 as it should be fully compatible with Ubuntu 16.04.3, but the issue is identical expect for the blinking '_' that is not even present anymore. Fortunately i could access tty to uninstall the drivers.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar problems with the AMD driver, once installed a reboot won't be successful.

To get OpenCL running I found these drivers

https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers

and used them, so far it worked for me.

From the description:

"This PPA provides updated X (2D) and mesa (3D) free graphics drivers for radeon, intel and nvidia hardware. Updates packages provide:

- OpenGL 4.5+ support and new OpenGL extensions: http:// mesamatrix net
- packages built against llvm-5.0
- gallium-nine support installed by default. Read the specific section below
- VDPAU, OpenMAX IL Bellagio, VAAPI and XvMC Gallium3D accelerated video drivers (see below)
- OpenCL support (mesa-opencl-icd package), including updated libclc
- r600 LLVM compiler, enabled with R600_DEBUG=llvm env var
- optional GLAMOR acceleration on radeon (>= r300), and nouveau drivers
- experimental ilo (intel) and virgl (virtio-gpu) gallium drivers"

---

Edited to add:
Here

https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/linux-graphics-x-org-drivers/opengl-vulkan-mesa-gallium3d/24959-updated-and-optimized-ubuntu-free-graphics-drivers/page173?50038-Updated-and-Optimized-Ubuntu-Free-Graphics-Drivers=

is a link to a Phoronix forum thread where the maintainer of the above PPA is very active.

Comment: Yes, i'm usiing oibaf too now and they seem to be more stable while still supporting OpenCL.